# How? Create AlertDialog inside AsyncTask and then use the result to continue the task

Tags: android, android-studio

So here is what I'm supposed to do, first, when user press a button, an AlertDialog will pop up and ask the user to enter something, then I get the String from the user and go ahead to search for it on the internet, which should be done in an AsyncTask. So far so good, I don't have any problems with that. But the part that confuses me is that, there might be multiple results, and I need to pop up a new AlertDialog that displays all the results I found and then ask the user to choose one specific result. I know this should be done on the MainThread, still, I don't have a problem, but the problem is, how do I get the thing that the user chose, and use it to continue my AsyncTask?

Thank you!

Comment: according to what I have understood, once you have got the results then call the same async task again by passing the results

Comment: Thanks @AdnanMomin, but, if I call the same AsyncTask again, let's call it task2 and the current AsyncTask task1, will task1 continue to run after task2 has returned? Because if yes, task1 will return a null object and cause some problem. Or maybe I should add statements to the AsyncTask to handle "null" situations?

Comment: once you have got the result then in `onPostExecute()` you can call the async task again with the results. And in `onPostExecute()` before calling the task you just have to check condition to call or not to call.

Comment: @AdnanMomin Thanks! I did it this way and it works, actually it pretty simple, I don't know why it had me for so many hours. Thank you very much!

Comment: can you will please vote me

Comment: `then call the same async task again`. Impossible. An AsyncTask can only be executed once. One has to create a new AsyncTask and execute that one. @Adnan Momin.

Comment: @greenapps by **then call the same async task again** i meant use `new MyAsyncTask().execute();` in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is

[AutoCompleteTexView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) in a Alert dialog and add a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Call the Asynctask whenever the text changes in TextWatcher and update the adapter of AutoCompleteTexView.

Good thing is AutoCompleteTexView comes with inbuilt suggestion list and onItemClickListener. So that you can the pick the user clicked item.

If your search result is more than a string, then you may have to use the custom adapter and custom filter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks albeee! I'll go ahead and try it now